# Why not set `task` option for the watch task in Gruntfile?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

In a Gruntfile.js, I saw codes like this:

```
watch: {
 jsTest: {
    files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
    tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
  },
  gruntfile: {
    files: ['Gruntfile.js']
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
    },
    files: [
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
      '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
    ]
  }
},
```

I really can't understand this part

gruntfile: {
    files: ['Gruntfile.js']
  },

And the following `livereload` part..

It seems that it wants to watch `Gruntfile.js` but didn't assign any `tasks` option to it. So nothing will happen when `Gruntfile.js` is changed.. Then what is the point to add this to the `watch` list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They [implemented a new feature](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/32) in version 0.4.0 to allow reloading of all Grunt configuration when the `Gruntfile.js` file changes. To do so, no task may be specified.

In other words, if you were to specify the `tasks` option, then Grunt would not reload its own configuration when changed. The way you have it, all config will be updated when Gruntfile.js itself changes.

For example, if you are watching some JS files and you change the config for your `jsTest` task (for example, you add a new folder of files to watch), then because you are also watching `Gruntfile.js` your new `jsTest` config will be automatically reloaded without having to stop and start the `watch` task.

Comment: do you mind explaining what is the purpose of this feature with example?

Comment: I added a better example at the bottom. Let me know if you have other questions.